# How to prove that sum of two rational numbers can only be a rational number

Tags: algebra-precalculus, proof-writing, rational-numbers

so here is what i have attempted, suppose we have two rational numbers $s$ and $t$, $s = \frac{p}{q}$ and $t = \frac{m}{n}$

adding these together results in a number of the form $\frac{pn + qm}{qn}$, and this satisfies the definition of the rational number.

we can further show that integers are closed in multiplication, and addition, so the both denominator and numerator are integers as well.

I think that's enough, or do i need something else.

Comment: If the question is "show that addition of rationals is well defined", then one must demonstrate that $\frac{p}{q}+\frac{m}{n}=\frac{p'}{q'}+\frac{m'}{n'}$ whenever $\frac{p}{q}=\frac{p'}{q'}$ and $\frac{m}{n}=\frac{m'}{n'}$. If the question is "show that sums of rational real numbers are also rational", then one must demonstrate that the embedding $i$ of rationals into the reals satisfies $i(s+t) = i(s) + i(t)$. There's insufficient context here to judge what's being asked.

Comment: That's enough.  (Depending on how numbers are defined and introduced it may even be too much. )

Comment: A *lot* of courses will introduce rational numbers as an ordered field.  As ordered fields are, by definition, closed under addition there is nothing to prove.  But I assume you are not taking one of those courses.